# Is it possible to iterate a set of feature file lines based on the arraylist returned by a step definition

Tags: java, cucumber

Scenario: one step definition returns an ArrayList and I want to run the next lines in the feature file n number of times depending on the size of the ArrayList with a course of actions being performed on each element from the list.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Not certain how that helps you. Perhaps you wanted to ask how to iterate a set of feature file lines based on the arraylist returned by a step definition? You should explain what feature file lines are, and show us your step definition. In fact, without any code, your question can only be answered with "yes".